# systemd service iptables-restore enabled but does not start after boot

Tags: iptables, gentoo

I have a Gentoo system (Base System release 2.2) and want to load iptables rules on startup automatically.

Therefore I try to get a systemd service `iptables-restore` to run on startup.

the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables-restore.service` looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restore iptables firewall rules
# if both are queued for some reason, don't store before restoring :)
Before=iptables-store.service
# sounds reasonable to have firewall up before any of the services go up
Before=network.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables-restore /var/lib/iptables/rules-save

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

i then do

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable iptables-restore.service
systemctl start iptables-restore
systemctl status iptables-restore
```

after the service has been started the iptables rules are sucessfully applied and can get checked with `iptables -L`

but the status shows:

```
● iptables-restore.service - Restore iptables firewall rules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables-restore.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Also after reboot the rules are not applied.

Furthermore I made another systemd service with the same content but changed `WantedBy=basic.target` to `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

But that also didn't work...

Any hints on how to get the systemd service to run on startup or alternative approaches how to apply iptables rules on startup?

Comment: Try adding `RemainAfterExit=yes` under the `Type=oneshot` line (and do a daemon-reload)

Comment: Thx status looks better after manual start but did start after reboot

Comment: The service being `inactive (dead)` just means that it did it's job to run `ExecStart=` once (`oneshot`) and is no more needed. This is independent of the status of the command to be run. Is `iptables` maybe depending on `network.target`?

Comment: Maybe it is dependent on network.target. so it should be "After=network.target" rather that "Before=network.target"?

Comment: `default.target` actually might be the best option

Comment: Wantedby=default.target?

Comment: Yes, give it a try.

Comment: didn't work...It is hopeless :-( Is there any other way to have a script started after startup besides systemd-service, init.d, local.d and cron :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables-restore /var/lib/iptables/rules-save
```

`iptables-restore` doesn't take filenames as command line arguments. Per the man (emphasis mine):

> iptables-restore is used to restore IP Tables from data specified on **STDIN**. Use I/O redirection provided by your shell to read from a file

You need to pass the file in via redirection:

```
ExecStart='/sbin/iptables-restore < /var/lib/iptables/rules-save'
```