# execute script on startup without rc-update

Tags: gentoo, sysvinit, rc

I want to execute a script that sets iptable rules on each startup.

I read about the option to write a `*.start` script to `/etc/local.d` [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/local.d), but I cannot execute `rc-update add local default` to add 
*init.d script to the default runlevel*.

But there is no `rc-update` on my system.

```
rc-update: command not found
```

I also consider to write a startup script to `/etc/init.d/` as described [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/Initscripts#Writing_initscripts%60) but again there is no `rc-update` on my system

How can I configure a script to execute on startup without rc-update?

What exactly does rc-update?

Can I do the same manually?

Comment: I'd suggest using a `systemd`-service for this.

Comment: I already tried to use a systemd but it is not running on startup. see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548253/systemd-service-iptables-restore-enabled-but-does-not-start-after-boot)

Comment: You should rather go that route, then. `basic.target` is too early, I think.

Comment: Thx, multi-user.target also didn't work.. any recommendations on later targets?

Comment: Maybe `requires=network.target` (or `after=`). Not too sure about the dependencies of `iptables`, though.

Comment: Please provide the output of `emerge -av systemd` to determine what init you are using.  Answer N.